# Enable Touch In FullCalendar In Android ADB

Tags: android, webview, fullcalendar

I want to enable touch input in fullCalendar and make a fullcalendar website to work in Android ADB and localhost as well. I can access my site in ADB and in localhost, but I can't touch in calendar boxes in android ADB. 
I try to include in site header the jQuery UI Touch Punch (`punch.js`), without success.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/punch.js"></script>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css.map">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

The script.js contains my calendar and i declare it that way:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
},
defaultView: 'month',
editable: true,
selectable: true,
allDaySlot: false,
displayEventTime: true,
slotDuration: '03:00:00',
contentHeight: 'auto',
```

Then I use functions like:

```
eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    endtime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end).format('h:mm');
    starttime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
    var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
    $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
    $('#modalWhen').text(mywhen);
    $('#eventID').val(event.id);
    $('#calendarModal').modal();
},
```

I also use Bootstrap style in HTML Declaration:

```
 <div class ="row">
    <!-- add calander in this div -->
    <div class="container">
        <div id="calendar">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In PC Web browser this work as expected, but in android web browser won't react when I touch on calendar event boxes.

Is there any way to make my site to recognize touch on the calendar event boxes?

UPDATE: Drag And Drop Works when I update to latest chrome version in Android 7.0 ADB, but the event clicks and click on blank boxes to add events not work.

Comment: Without any code or specific description of what touch functionality you're having a problem with it's difficult to be sure what the precise problem is. Normally I'd expect a "click" event handler to respond to a finger tap in a mobile device. Have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch?

Comment: Thanks for the information! My code is long enough to attach it. I can attach some parts of the code If it is required.

Comment: We just need enough code and information to be able to understand, and ideally reproduce, the stated problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance. So yes, please post enough relevant parts so that someone here could see the issue themselves if they executed the code. (You may even find that, by going through the exercise of reducing the code down to only the parts necessary for the problem to exist, you might even find that you discover for yourself where the issue lies. It's a useful debugging technique).

Comment: Let's minimise it a bit more - remove the punch.js and all the bootstrap guff and reduce it to just the calendar on its own. Make it show a simple alert when the event is clicked. Then we know it's actually the event click which isn't working, rather than something being wrong with the code within the event handler.

Comment: Yes, Is not working when i minimize it as well and also not working when i visit the official fullcalendar website . I need to have click able events to delete them and the empty boxes to be able to add new events .

Comment: Ok, which version of fullCalendar? Which specific browser and version? Have you tried with any other mobile browsers e.g. Firefox? It would be useful to know if it's specific to any particular (version of a) browser. And have you searched fullCalendar's bug list on GitHub to see if any similar issue has been raised previously?

Comment: Ok, I update to latest Version of full calendar, latest chrome in Android adb. It work ok now when i drag the events. It is as expected in the full calendar website as well.  But, in my code i cant do some features that worked in the PC browser. I still can't tap on events to select and i can only drag it. I can't tap to the empty space to add new event.

Comment: As per that link I gave you, to trigger the select callback (in order to select an empty space), you must press down on the empty slot on the calendar for 1 second, not just tap. You can adjust the selectLongPressDelay setting if you want to alter that.

Comment: Here's a super-simple runnable demo using your minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/2/ . Does this allow you to tap on the events? You should see the event title pop up in an alert when you do.

Comment: I long press for about 5 seconds .... And Yes, now is Working !!! Thank you very much! I will change the delay and let you know!

Comment: With longPressDelay: 10, eventLongPressDelay: 20,selectLongPressDelay: 25 the issue is solved!

Comment: You can add it as answer to accept it. It really help me a lot. I spent a lot of time on this issue.

Comment: No problem. BTW if you specify `eventLongPressDelay: 20,selectLongPressDelay: 25` then you don't need `longPressDelay: 10` since the two other settings both override it. longPressDelay is only useful if you want to give the same delay to both situations. The documentation makes this clear.

Comment: Great! That's Awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trigger the "select" callback (in order to select an empty space), you must press down on the empty slot on the calendar for 1 second, not just tap. You can adjust the `selectLongPressDelay` setting if you want to alter that, e.g.

```
selectLongPressDelay: 25
```

Meanwhile, `eventClick` should just work on touch devices without any further adjustment. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/3/) is a demo which illustrates that.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch for more details.